# Run external Powershell scripts form Dart

Tags: powershell, dart, command-line

On trying to pass and return values from an external Powershell script,Dart doesn't execute the Powershell script(tried with both `cmd` and `powershell`)and only returns the runtimeType `Instance of 'ProcessResult'`.

Is there a way to communicate with external Powershell scripts?

***Dart2Ps.dart***

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  // With Cmd
  var script_cmd = 'type "F:\Script\Dart\dart_tests\process\SumScript.ps1" | powershell.exe -c -';
  List<int> args = [1, 2];
  var sum_cmd = await Process.run('cmd', ['args', script_cmd]);
  stdout.write(sum_cmd.stdout);
  print(sum_cmd);

  // With Powershell
  var script_ps =
      'powershell -File "F:\Script\Dart\dart_tests\process\SumScript.ps1"';
  var sum_ps = await Process.run('powershell', ['args', script_ps]);
  stdout.write(sum_ps.stdout);
  print(sum_ps);
}
```

***SumScript.ps1***

```
$sum = $args[0] + $args[1] 

Write-Host '$sum from Powershell'

return $sum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to place the ***dart+powershell*** files in ***dart /lib folder***.

**Dart Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print(runPowerShellScript(r'C:\tmp\SumScript.ps1', ['1', '2']));
  // $sum from Powershell
  // 3
}

String runPowerShellScript(String scriptPath, List<String> argumentsToScript) {
  return Process.runSync(
          'Powershell.exe', ['-File', scriptPath, ...argumentsToScript]).stdout
      as String;
}
```

**Powershell Code:**

```
$sum = $args[0] + $args[1]  
Write-Host '$sum from Powershell' 
return $sum
```